# Calling Constructors in Multi-Level Inheritance WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance

I am having trouble calling base constructors in wpf windows:

```
public class TemplateWindow : Window //Template window class
{
    public TemplateWindow (int no)
    {
    }
}

public partial class MainView : TemplateWindow
{
    public MainView() : base(1) //error here
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

It gives me an error at the indicated location as it apparently is trying to call the Window constructor with base instead. The MainView class is the code behind of a xaml window.

However, when I tested the problem like below, it works perfectly fine.

```
class A //Base Class
{
    public A() { }
}

class B : A
{
    public B(int no) { }
}

partial class C : B
{
    public C() : base(1) { }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You should post the actual error that it gives you.

Comment: Agree w/ Gabe; please post your stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your `MainView` class defined in XAML, don't you? It probably goes something like this:

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.MainView" ... >
    ...
</Window>
```

Note the big `Window` word right at the beginning. It tells the compiler that you want this XAML to generate a class named `MyNamespace.MainView`, and you want it to inherit from `Window`. So that's what the compiler does: it happily generates your class and makes it inherit from `Window`. Right-click the `InitializeComponent` word and choose "Go to Definition". This will take you to the autogenerated file, and you'll be able to see the class.

Now, if you want `MainView` to inherit from `TemplateWindow`, you just have to say so in your XAML:

```
<my:TemplateWindow 
    xmlns:my="MyNamespace" 
    x:Class="MyNamespace.MainView" ... >
    ...
</my:TemplateWindow>
```

But that will give you another problem: now, all of a sudden, you can't use the visual designer.

That would be because the designer cannot create an instance of your `TemplateWindow` class for editing. Why? Well, because `TemplateWindow` doesn't have a default constructor, of course!

So for this kind of thing to work, you'll just have to define two constructors in `TemplateWindow` - one default, and one accepting an `int`.

Good luck.

Comment: Yes I see my problem now. But how do I get around it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer
http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2007/03/02/107747.aspx

Comment: Thanks, it confirms what Fyodor Soikin has posted above